# how to get image url throuh api and then build image widget in listView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In ListView, I will initially call list of data from api and then in response image data, **filePath** will be received, After that loaded list will builded through listview widget and its children were image widget need to call another api get url and then rebuild again

Below Code have issues, just take for reference

```
List url=[];
SizedBox(
  height: 150,
  child: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
      SizedBox(
          height: 150,
          child: ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: response.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Hero(
                      tag: 'imageHero $index',
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          
                        },
                        child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            child: Image.network(
                              url[index] ??
                                  "",
                              height: 110,
                              width: 150,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              
                              loadingBuilder: (context, child,
                                  loadingProgress) {
                          final response = Api.getUrl(response.data[index] 
                                                    ['FilePath']).then((){
                              list.add(response.data);
                                    });

                                return child;
                              },
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                  ],
                );
              })),
```